# How to do it so the code executes down the function after not passing a condition?

Tags: javascript

The following function does the following:

1) Check if the object has non-empty categories (keys with a certain name).

2) Check each of the objects inside those categories. If the object has the property `web` and the property is not empty or undefined return `false`.

3) The last bit does the same, but when the property `web` is in the object not in the categories.

```
hasNoCategories (object) {
  for (let key in object) {
    const value = object[key]
    const isCategory = this.categories.indexOf(key) > -1
    if (value.constructor === Array && isCategory && value.length > 0) {
      let result
      value.map(pano => {
        if (pano.web !== undefined && pano.web !== '') {
          result = false
        }
      })
      // STUCK HERE
      return result
    }
    if (key === 'web' && value !== '') {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
},
```

However, when the code sometimes stops in `// STUCK HERE` and never makes it to return `true` at the end.

One workaround is this:

```
if (pano.web !== undefined && pano.web !== '') {
  result = false
} else {
  result = true
}
```

But I'm against having two `return true`, I feel it kinds of muddle the logic (I just want to have one `return true`, the one at the end.)

How to modify the code so the code doesn't get stuck in `// STUCK HERE` and continues until reaching `return true`?

**EDIT:**

Sample input:

```
{
  "livingroom": [],
  "diningroom": [],
  "kitchen": [],
  "bedroom": [],
  "study": [],
  "bathroom": [],
  "toilet": [],
  "garden": [],
  "garage": [],
  "outdoors": [],
  "other": [],
  "id": "ZI4hteKxgr",
  "name": "Cuiti",
  "description": "",
  "visible": true,
  "user": "",
  "floorplan": "",
  "shareCode": "http://vrviewer.istaging.co#!/854703",
  "date": "2016/5/13",
  "isDirty": false
}
```

Comment: When you reach a return, the function stops. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Description) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Interrupt_a_function)

Comment: In the first `if` statement, if `result` doesn't become `false` then it is returning `undefined` and the function ends like @zer00ne mentioned.

Comment: @DonovanM So how can I do it so the function resumes and not end when returning `undefined`?

Comment: Also when you use `let` you are limiting the scope of `key` to only the `for` loop. If you hope to reach that return true with a `key`, try `var`. Read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/2813224).

Comment: I believe that's why your *workaround* works, is because it's within scope of `key`.

Comment: @alex You could use a `for` loop instead of `map` and only `return false` if that condition is met.

Comment: @DonovanM Could you post an answer illustrating that?

Comment: Sure thing. Writing it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is example of doing this using a `for` loop instead of `map` for the first `if` statement.

```
hasNoCategories (object) {
  for (let key in object) {
    const value = object[key]
    const isCategory = this.categories.indexOf(key) > -1
    if (value.constructor === Array && isCategory && value.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0, len = value.length; i < len; i++) {
        let pano = value[i]
        if (pano.web !== undefined && pano.web !== '') {
          return false
        }
      }
    }
    if (key === 'web' && value !== '') {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

This could probably be done in a cleaner way, though. I think `for` loops tend to make code look less clean.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I can't think of a way of not using `for loop`s though